# Как сделать чтобы текст из lable редактировался с помощью нажатия кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

Чтобы get. извлекала текст из поля entry и обновляла на кнопку редактирвоать [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tkinter import *



root = Tk()
root.title("Данные")
root.geometry("1280x200")
root.resizable(False, False)

redname1 = StringVar()
redname2 = StringVar()
redname3 = StringVar()
redname4 = StringVar()
redname5 = StringVar()



def namebas():
    name2 = Label(text=get.redname1())
    name1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    name2 = Label(text=get.redname2())
    name2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    name3 = Label(text=get.redname3())
    name3.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    name4 = Label(text=get.redname4())
    name4.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    name5 = Label(text=get.redname5())
    name5.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)



name1red = Entry(textvariable=redname1)
name1red.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name2red = Entry(textvariable=redname2)
name2red.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name3red = Entry(textvariable=redname3)
name3red.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name4red = Entry(textvariable=redname4)
name4red.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name5red = Entry(textvariable=redname5)
name5red.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)


name1 = Label(text=redname1)
name1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name2 = Label(text=redname2)
name2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name3 = Label(text=redname3)
name3.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name4 = Label(text=redname4)
name4.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name5 = Label(text=redname5)
name5.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)


message_button1 = Button(text="Редактировать", command=namebas)
message_button1.grid(row=0,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button2 = Button(text="Редактировать", command=namebas)
message_button2.grid(row=1,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button3 = Button(text="Редактировать", command=namebas)
message_button3.grid(row=2,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button4 = Button(text="Редактировать", command=namebas)
message_button4.grid(row=3,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button5 = Button(text="Редактировать", command=namebas)
message_button5.grid(row=4,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В функции `namebas()` вы первой строкой объявляете `name2`, хотя как я понимаю, там должно быть `name1`
2. Вместо того, чтобы брать значение из переменных, я бы порекомендовал брать значения прямо из `Entry`. То есть, вместо `get.redname1()` делать так - `name1red.get()`
3. Также проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, если у вас поля `Entry` окажутся пустыми, то ваши текстовые метки `Label` тоже примут пустое значение. Поэтому вам нужно при нажатии на конкретную кнопку отправлять в функцию определенный ключ, чтобы менялось только одно значение.

**Добавим передачу аргумента в функцию (команда при нажатии кнопки):**

`command = lambda x=1: namebas(x)`

**Добавим в функцию проверку кнопки:**

```
def namebas(x):
    if x == 1:
        name1['text'] = name1red.get()
    if x == 2:
        name2['text'] = name2red.get()
    if x == 3:
        name3['text'] = name3red.get()
    if x == 4:
        name4['text'] = name4red.get()
    if x == 5:
        name5['text'] = name5red.get()
```

---

Все это, конечно, не оптимизировано, но думаю идея ясна.

### Полный код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Данные")
root.geometry("1280x200")
root.resizable(False, False)


def namebas(x):
    if x == 1:
        name1['text'] = name1red.get()
    if x == 2:
        name2['text'] = name2red.get()
    if x == 3:
        name3['text'] = name3red.get()
    if x == 4:
        name4['text'] = name4red.get()
    if x == 5:
        name5['text'] = name5red.get()



name1red = Entry()
name1red.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name2red = Entry()
name2red.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name3red = Entry()
name3red.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name4red = Entry()
name4red.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

name5red = Entry()
name5red.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)


name1 = Label(text='1')
name1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name2 = Label(text='2')
name2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name3 = Label(text='3')
name3.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name4 = Label(text='4')
name4.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

name5 = Label(text='5')
name5.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)


message_button1 = Button(text="Редактировать", command = lambda x=1: namebas(x))
message_button1.grid(row=0,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button2 = Button(text="Редактировать", command = lambda x=2: namebas(x))
message_button2.grid(row=1,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button3 = Button(text="Редактировать", command = lambda x=3: namebas(x))
message_button3.grid(row=2,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button4 = Button(text="Редактировать", command = lambda x=4: namebas(x))
message_button4.grid(row=3,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

message_button5 = Button(text="Редактировать", command = lambda x=5: namebas(x))
message_button5.grid(row=4,column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```